Find the Number 77 with the numbers 2,0,2,4
Hi everyone this is a second post to finding the numbers to this challenge the number that I’m looking for is 77.
Link to the Paper I’m Trying to Solve: https://mathequalslove.net/yearly-number-challenge/
(I notice that it has been changed to 2025 but the rules are still the same the numbers are the only difference so please use 2024)
Link to my other post: Find the Numbers 50-70 Using 2,0,2,4
Have a good day everyone!

Welcome to Puzzling! Please could you edit your question to include all required information, instead of just linking to an external source.

Please don't repost the same question a second time. I understand that you're eager to find a solution for 77, but reposting is not the way to go about it.

Also sorry F1Krazy I wasn’t aware of that
